# How to get rid of paint smell

Tags: cleaning, home, smell

We are painting the whole house one room at a time, but as I suffer from asthma, I avoid the smell as much as possible but right now the whole house smell of paint, although I have opened windows.

Is there a way to get rid of the smell of paint otherwise?

Comment: This is not an answer, but a suggestion for next time.  

We have lots of low VOC paint in Australia, one brand Livos (made in Germany) is worth considering. I've used it on ceilings, walls, and the oil for timber floors and external decks. No doubt LA has lots more options in 'natural' sealants.

I'd be dumping the paint you have if you can afford to do that, and exploring healthier options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try heating the painted rooms to speed up the drying process. You also want lots of ventilation, e.g. by opening the windows on opposite sides of the house so you get a nice breeze going (block the doors to prevent them from banging shut).

The smell is caused by the volatile components of the paint evaporating (as Stan mentioned). This can take weeks, depending on the type of paint you used.

You can also look into using a different type of paint. Oil/turpentine-based paints smell much more than acrylics (water-based paint).

Answer (score 0):

Chemical Sensitivity and "Sick Building" Syndrome

With advanced oxidation, ozone generators are designed to destroy, not just cover up, the smell of industrial odours caused by VOC's (volatile organic compounds) given off by new carpets, **paints**, cleaning chemicals and other building materials.

Ozone Shock Treatment is effective at breaking down VOC's, making it an effective treatment for those who are sensitive to chemical smells in the air. Ozone treatment will restore the air to a fresh, breathable, safe condition.

Ozone generators are available for rent in some places. It's probably a good thing to not be in the same place during ozone shock treatment until the place has been aired out.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Baking soda is known as a natural scent absorber, it is also relatively inexpensive. You can place a few bowls around a home to absorb the smell. If you want to try out something else, you can try the same technique with vinegar, water with lemons, coffee grounds, or onions. It may also help to have some lit candles and fans set up around your home.